# GetManifestResourceNames: Some resources are not embedded (Not authorized?)

Tags: .net, embedded-resource

When the embedded resource is named with this kind pattern:

whatever.{xxx}.whatever

Replace {xxx} with one of the following examples: agq,arn,asa,ast,bas,bem,bez,bin. Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames won't find them. There are about a hundred of them. (Check the code below to find them all)

I keep getting the same results be it with .Net framework or .Net core.

Is this kind of naming unauthorized because it looks like some sort of forbidden extension file name? If so, how to disable this dumb security rule.

```
        List<string> codes = new List<string>();

        for (char first = 'a'; first <= (int)'z'; first++)
            for (char second = 'a'; second <= (int)'z'; second++)
                for (char third = 'a'; third <= (int)'z'; third++)
                    codes.Add(first.ToString() + second + third);

        codes = codes.Take(1000).ToList();



        string slnPath = Directory.GetParent(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).FullName;
        while (!Directory.GetFiles(slnPath).Any(x => x.EndsWith(".sln")))
            slnPath = Directory.GetParent(slnPath).FullName;

        string classLibraryFolder = "ClassLibrary1";
        var csjFolder = Path.Combine(slnPath, classLibraryFolder);
        var csjPath = Path.Combine(csjFolder, $"{classLibraryFolder}.csproj");            
        string resourcesFolder = "Resources";
        string resourcesPath = Path.Combine(csjFolder, resourcesFolder);

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(csjPath);
        if(!doc.Descendants().Attributes().Any(x=> x.Value == $"{resourcesFolder}\\x.aaa.x"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creating embedded resources...");                

            Directory.CreateDirectory(resourcesPath);

            foreach (var code in codes)
                File.Create(Path.Combine(resourcesPath, "x." + code + ".x")).Close();

            Console.WriteLine("Updating csproj...");

            var xNone = new XElement("ItemGroup");
            foreach (var code in codes)
                xNone.Add(new XElement("None", new XAttribute("Remove", $"{resourcesFolder}\\x.{code}.x")));

            var xEmbeddedResource = new XElement("ItemGroup");
            foreach (var code in codes)
                xEmbeddedResource.Add(new XElement("EmbeddedResource", new XAttribute("Include", $"{resourcesFolder}\\x.{code}.x")));

            doc.Root.Add(xNone);
            doc.Root.Add(xEmbeddedResource);
            doc.Save(csjPath);

            Console.WriteLine("Please relaunch program.");
            return;
        }


        string[] Languages2 = typeof(ClassLibrary1.Class1).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().ToArray();

        var present = codes.Where(code => Languages2.Any(x => x.EndsWith($"x.{code}.x"))).ToList();
        var missing = codes.Except(present).ToList();
```

Comment: Brr, fighting the .csproj file wasn't a lot of fun.  You'll find the missing resources in their own satellite assembly instead of getting embedded in the dll.  This decision is made by the msbuild [AssignCulture task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/assignculture-task).  Why it thinks that "bin", "bez", etc are valid culture identifiers is not obvious to me.  You'll want a different naming convention to avoid this.

Comment: Compare to [this list](https://github.com/kendo-labs/bower-kendo-ui/tree/master/js/cultures).